# Unable to display the first image properly when using adaptiveHeight

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have a slick slider and I want the height to change based on the image that is currently being displayed.The images for my slider is not hard-coded.The images are taken from input file and then displayed into the slider.I added adaptiveHeight: true and it worked.My height will change automatically but when I upload the images and not touch anything else, the image is not displayed properly.Only when I click next or previous then will the images be properly displayed.

**HTML:**

```
<section name="canvas" class="canvas" id="canvas">
   <div id="boxContain"></div>
   <div class="imageContainer" id="imageContainer">
   </div>
</section>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById('my_file');
const fileList = document.getElementById('imageContainer');
let slickSettings = {
    infinite: true,
    draggable: false,
    arrows: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    swipe: false,
    adaptiveHeight: true
};
let initSlickCarousel = (target, settings) => {
    const $target = $(target);

    switch (true) {
        case $target.hasClass('slick-initialized'):
            $target.slick('unslick');
            $target.slick(settings);
            break;
        default:
            $target.slick(settings);
    }
};
const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log('We are handling it sir!');
    const filesArray = Array.from(event.target.files);
    if (filesArray.length > 20) {
        alert("Please select 20 or less images!!");
    } else {
        filesArray.map((singleFile) => {
            const outputImg = document.createElement('img');
            const fileReader = new FileReader();

            outputImg.className = 'img-thumbnail';

            fileReader.readAsDataURL(singleFile);

            fileReader.onload = (event) => {
                outputImg.src = event.target.result;
                document.getElementById("canvas").style.height = "auto";
                document.getElementById("imageContainer").style.height = "auto";
                document.getElementById("imageContainer").style.width = "auto";
                document.getElementById("createBoxBtn").style.pointerEvents = ("auto");
                document.getElementById("duplicateBox").style.pointerEvents = ("auto");
                document.getElementById("deleteBox").style.pointerEvents = ("auto");
                document.getElementById("save").style.pointerEvents = ("auto");

            };


            console.log(outputImg);
            console.log(event.target.files);
            fileList.appendChild(outputImg);
            document.getElementById("openBtn").style.pointerEvents = "none";

        });
        var files = event.target.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            $("#files").append('<div class="filename"><span name="fileNameList">' + files[i].name + '</span></div>');
        }

        initSlickCarousel(fileList, slickSettings);
    }

};
```

**CSS:**

```
 .canvas {
     border: 1px solid black;
     width: 600px;
     height: 600px;
     background: #D3D3D3;
     position: absolute;
     margin-left: 350px;
}
```

After I upload the images and not touch anything, the height will become so small that you can't see the full image.Only after I click next/prev then it will show the full image.It should show full image from the beginning and not need to click next/prev to adjust.So how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you set the size for each image? It might be because when the slick initialized itself, it didn't read the `height` property from CSS. If you can provide an actual code example, it would be helpful to debug.

Comment: @Speir no i didnt set height for each image.I'll put the codes into a jsFiddle.

Comment: By reading your code, I think you are setting up images after intializing the slick right?

Comment: @Speir yes that is correct

Comment: If you can preset the image size, I think it will be all good.

Comment: @Speir preset meaning setting a height for the images?

Comment: yep, just set the height and width for the image in CSS, I think it will do the job.

Comment: @Speir hm..but i want the div to match the image height and the height can be anything since the image is based on user upload...so how would i go about setting the height?

Comment: Can you get your code in the jsfiddle up and running? It's easier for me to do it there.

Comment: @Speir https://jsfiddle.net/3wng7xaj/1/

Comment: That's not working for me. Your HTML still contains PHP code. My advice is to initialize slick after the user uploading more than 2 images.

Comment: @Speir the php codes can be removed.https://jsfiddle.net/3wng7xaj/2/

Comment: Somehow I can only upload one image, then the open button not working anymore, the image also only shows a small proportion

Comment: @Speir that is correct.I made it that way as if i were to select a set of images,it would display a slider.But when i select another set of images again it would display below the slider.So i disabled the button to prevent that problem.You can select a set of multiple images.Display a small portion of the image is the issue im facing.

Comment: Is that box changing it's size based on image size? For me, the grey box stays in a fix size.

Comment: @Speir the height is supposed to change based on image size.I am currently still trying to figure out how to make the width change based on image.

Comment: That's because you are setting a fixed width and height to 500px. If you want it to be dynamic, you need to set the max-height and max-width and make the width and height of canvas 100%.

Comment: @Speir I tried setting the width to 100% and max-width: 500px but the width of the slider still remains at 500px

Comment: My work around is to set the `adpative-height` property after the init but before the first change.
https://jsfiddle.net/6hnzrdx8/26/

Comment: @Speir Thank you so much for your help!It is working. Please put as answer so i can accept!:)

Answer (score 2):

We use slick as our slider option a lot. My experience is that `adaptive-height` is not working very well with lazy loading images or when images are added after the slick is initialized.

In your case, the workaround is to set the `adaptive-height` property after the init but before the first change.

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById('my_file');
const fileList = document.getElementById('imageContainer');
let slickSettings = {
    infinite: true,
    draggable: false,
    arrows: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    swipe: false,
    /* adaptiveHeight: true */

};
let initSlickCarousel = (target, settings) => {
    const $target = $(target);

        $target.slick(settings);
    
};
const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log('We are handling it sir!');
    const filesArray = Array.from(event.target.files);
    if (filesArray.length > 20) {
        alert("Please select 20 or less images!!");
    } else {
        filesArray.map((singleFile) => {
            const outputImg = document.createElement('img');
            const fileReader = new FileReader();

            outputImg.className = 'img-thumbnail';

            // Let's read it as data url - onload won't return a thing without it
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(singleFile);

            fileReader.onload = (event) => {
                outputImg.src = event.target.result;
            };  

            console.log(outputImg);
            console.log(event.target.files);
            fileList.appendChild(outputImg);
            document.getElementById("openBtn").style.pointerEvents = "none";

        });
        var files = event.target.files;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            $("#files").append('<div class="filename"><span name="fileNameList">' + files[i].name + '</span></div>');
        }

        initSlickCarousel(fileList, slickSettings);
        if ($(".imageContainer").hasClass("slick-initialized")) {
          console.log($(".imageContainer").slick('slickGetOption','adaptiveHeight'));

          $('.imageContainer').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
       $(".imageContainer").slick('slickSetOption','adaptiveHeight', true, true);
          });
        }
    }

};



if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList) { // check if browser can handle this

    console.log('We are good to go sir!');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', handleInputChange, false);

} else {

    alert('File features are not fully supported. Please consider changing the browser (newest Chrome or Mozilla).');
}
```

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,600,700);
#{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
}
html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,63,63, 1), rgba(244,21,122, 1));
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    padding: 5px;
}
.nav {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
#hiddenLink{
    display: none;
}
.canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: #D3D3D3;
/*    overflow: hidden;*/
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 350px;
}
#imageContainer{
    height: 100%;
}

.nav button {
    width: 100px;
}
.openBtn, input[type=submit] {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.openBtn:hover, input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
img {
    /*position:absolute;*/
/*    float: left;*/
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}

#boxContain{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 900;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Online Image Labelling Tool</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/4.1.1/photoswipe.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/4.1.1/default-skin/default-skin.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />


</head>

<body>
    <form name="imageLblForm" method="post" id="imageLblForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server" action="#">
        <h4 id="errorMessage"></h4>
        <section name="nav" class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="file" id="my_file" name="file1" onchange="" accept=".bmp,.jpg, .png, image/jpg, image/bmp, image/png" style="display:none" multiple /><input type="button" id="openBtn" class="openBtn" value="Open" onclick="document.getElementById('my_file').click();" /></li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Save" id="save" onclick="document.getElementById('hiddenLink').click(); return false; "><a id="hiddenLink">Save</a></li>
                <li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section name="canvas" class="canvas" id="canvas">
            <div id="boxContain"></div>
            <div class="imageContainer" id="imageContainer">
        
            </div>

        </section>
    </form>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://wp.incredibbble.com/writsy-shop/wp-content/themes/writsy-shop/assets/vendor/jquery-zoom/jquery.zoom.min.js?ver=1.7.18" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Speir..Your codes worked but after I implemented a Google Login on my web application,the grey box is not resizing again.

Comment: the grey box is just an example, it depends on your CSS and when you are setting the value of adaptiveHeight. Try figuring by yourself then you can improve.

Comment: I managed to do the auto height resize but it only works after i go through one round of the slides.